# SQL get Distinct rows from joined tables

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, join

I'm trying to determine the following from the joining of two tables:

Sample TableA: Contains 1 column consisting of unique IDs

```
ID    Name    Department
1     John    IT
2     Jason   Sales
3     Dany    IT
4     Mike    HR
5     Alex    HR
```

Sample TableB: Contains multiple columns, including ID from TableA. For example:

```
ID    AccountNumber    WebID
1     10725            ABC1
1     10726            ABC1
1     10727            ABC1
2     20100            ABC2
2     20101            ABC2
3     30100            ABC3
4     40100            NULL
```

I want to get the following results:

```
 ID   Name    WebID
 1    John    ABC1
 2    Jason   ABC2
 3    Dany    ABC3
 4    Mike    NULL
 5    Alex    NULL
```

I tried the following query, which is returning the correct rows for these sample tables:

```
Select count(a.ID), a.ID, a.Name, b.WebID from TableA a
left join TableB b on a.ID = b.ID
group by a.ID, a.Name, b.WebID
```

But my Actual Database tables, this query does not return correct number of rows: (30992)

```
TableA contains 29066 rows and TableB contains 23033 rows
```

The query should return 29066 rows, as it is Left Join.

When I checked the IDs that are in TableA, but not in TableB, there were 6033 rows:

```
Select * from TableA where ID not in (Select ID from TableB)
```

Am I missing something in the query?

Comment: You need a left outer join when table b does not ID that is in table A. You are only getting rows where Table A contains ID = 5.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Comment: It is the other way around @jdweng more ids in table a

Comment: Table A is an input. You do not want to change the inputs you want more data in the output.  The reason for the missing ids in the output is the output doesn't contain the ids that are not in Table B.  The reason is a simple join only gets ids from Table A.  You need the left outer join to get the missing ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TABLE B has duplicates of the ID column... the code below should work (but might not be the results you expect since I just do a max on the webid column which is fine if it is always the same but I need a rule if not)

I just saw you had a count... I added that in.

```
   SELECT A.ID, A.Name, B.WebID
   FROM TABLEA A
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT ID, MAX(WebID) AS WebID, count(*) as CNT
      FROM TABLEB
      GROUP BY ID
   ) B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: This query seems to be working. It is returning correct rows (29066). Count is not required.
However, instead of Select *, how do I select only specific columns from TableA and specific columns from TableB

Comment: @DevP -- updated to show you how to use the alias

Comment: This is a left join and that is why you are getting all the rows.  The is SQL query and not c# code.  Now you need to use left outer join in c#.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is as simple as that:

```
 select a.ID,a.Name,b.WebID 
 from TableA a 
 left join TableB b on a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: This does not returns Unique rows.